# Cannot access functions from an imported module under Python 3.5

Tags: python

I am trying to get a Python module called MTpy to run on my computer; this package allows handling and processing of magnetotelluric (geophysical) data.
I am using Python 3.5 with the Anaconda/Spyder IDE under Windows 10. 
I am just getting started with Python so I apologize if my question seems trivial!

My problem is, I can import the mtpy module and all of its submodules, but then I cannot call any of the functions contained in these subfolders.

For instance, mtpy contains a submodule called analysis.

I can successfully run:

```
import mtpy.analysis
```

Running

```
help(mtpy.analysis)
```

will return:

```
Help on package mtpy.analysis in mtpy:

NAME
    mtpy.analysis

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    distortion
    geometry
    niblettbostick
    pt
    staticshift
    zinvariants

FILE
    c:\users\sheldon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mtpy-0.0.1-py3.5.egg   \mtpy\analysis\__init__.py
```

However when trying to access the distortion.py function contained in the analysis folder, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-56-16963e2f7b1c>", line 1, in <module>
mtpy.analysis.distortion()

AttributeError: module 'mtpy.analysis' has no attribute 'distortion'
```

FYI, both my module (mtpy) and submodule folders (e.g. analysis) contain the init file.

Many thanks for your help!

Cheers,

Sheldon

Comment: *"access the `distortion.py` function"*?

Comment: Hi Moses, many thanks for your quick reply. Sorry if I was not clear enough! A file called distortion.py is contained in the analysis folder. When typing mtpy.analysis.distortion() in the Python terminal, I obtain the aforementionned error message.

Comment: You can't treat a module that way. Do `from mtpy.analysis import distortion` then call functions in the `distortion` module by doing `distortion.foo()`

Comment: Thanks Moses! I was able to call the functions in the "distortion" submodule using the syntax you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distortion.py` **isn't** a function it's a sub package of `analysis` and **it's not callable**. You can methods which is defined in [mtpy.analysis.distortion](https://github.com/geophysics/mtpy/blob/master/mtpy/analysis/distortion.py). You can get more info on [python 3 modules tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

**Good luck!**

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Andriy. I did not realize "distortion" was a submodule of "analysis". Your answer solved my issue!

Comment: @Sheldon Hey, you are welcome,  if it solved your problem could you mark answer as accepted ?